# Is there ever a rule not to place certain words on separate lines in a Sefer Torah?

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus, chulin-tractate

The Gemara in Chulin 64b - 65 discusses the Bas Hayaana bird, and explains that although that is indeed the name of the bird, the fact that it is two separate words allows us to also interpret them separately. From here we can derive that the egg (literally בת is daughter) of an 'unclean' bird is likewise prohibited.

> כתיב היענה וכתיב בת היענה ושאני הכא דפסק ספרא לשתי תיבות ומדפסיק להו ספרא בתרתי תיבות ש"מ תרי שמות נינהו אלא מעתה (בראשית יד, ד) את כדר לעומר דפסק להו ספרא בתרי הכי נמי דתרתי שמי נינהו אמרי התם בשתי תיבות פסיק להו בשני שיטין לא פסיק להו אבל הכא אפי' בשני שיטין נמי פסיק להו:

The Gemara contrasts these two words with כדר לעמר, which although it has a space, it is a nobrake space. It may not be split onto separate lines. Therefore, while כדר לעמר is only seen as one word, בת היענה is also seen as two words.

As it turns out, in our Sefarim we have it as one word כדרלעמר with no space at all.

My question is: do we have such an Halachah at all on another multi-word name, which would get a space but must remain on the same line?

Comment: There used to be a chumra to purposefully put בת היענה on two separate lines http://imhm.blogspot.com/2020/06/blog-post_24.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that custom still exists. The most famous example is the toponym בית-אל.

The Arukh HaShulchan ([YD 275](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%94):24) lists the following examples, though surely there are some variant customs out there: 
 תובל קין,
בית אל,
ומלכי צדק,
באר שבע,
בן אוני,
בעל חנן,
צפנת פענח,
פוטי פרע,
את והב,
משומו אל,
וחרה אף,
וחרה אפי,
כס יה
.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8248&st=&pgnum=129