Are there any multi-word names in the Tanakh?
The words יערי ארגים in 2 Samuel 21:19 are sometimes claimed to be a two-word name. (For example the KJV translates them that way.) Are there any other names in the Tanakh like this, which consist of two words with a space (or dash) between them?
There are lots of theophoric names like אלימלך composed of a few words fused together, but these are not what I am looking for.
There are also several names like בת שבע or בן הדד which start with "ben-" or "bat-". I am excluding these as well.

Yesss I was wondering this myself like 2 days ago...

Disclaimer: This list is not comprehensive. I'll update with more names suggested in the comments or that I have come across.

Yeshayahu had a son named מהר שלל חש בז (Maher Shalal Chash Baz)
(Isaiah 8:1-3).

Another of Yeshayahu's children was named שאר ישוב (Sha'ar Yeshuv)
(Isaiah 7:3).

There's also עמנו אל (Immanu El) (Isaiah 7:14) which, though
theophoric, is spelled with a space. It's not known whether he was
Yeshuayahu's son or Achaz's son (perhaps another name for
Chizkiyahu).

Menashe's mother was called חפצי־בה (Cheftzi-Bah) (Kings
2:21:1).

According to Metzudat David, there was a Levite named זכריהו בן
(Zecharyahu Ben) (Chronicles 1:15:18).1

In a simple reading of Hoshea, he had a daughter named לא רוחמה (Lo
Ruchama) and a son named לא עמי (Lo Ami) (Hosea
1:6-9).2

מלכי צדק (Malki Tzedek), king of Shalem, spelled like that both in Genesis 14:18
and Psalms 110:4.

אדני־צדק (Adoni-Tzedek) (Joshua 10:1-3), king of Yerushalayim.

אדני־בזק (Adoni-Bezek) (Judges 1:5-7), king of Bezek.

תובל קין (Tuval Kain) (Genesis 4:22), son of Lemech.

כל־חזה (Kol-Chozeh) (Nehemiah 11:5), the ancestor of a Judahite province head who lived in Yerushalayim.

אבי־עלבון (Avi-Elbon) (Samuel 2:23:31), one of the warriors of David.

מריב בעל (Meriv Baal) (Chronicles 1:8:34), the real name of Mephiboshet, son of Yonatan.

According to Metzudat Tzion and Radak, ישבי בנב (Yishbi Benov) (Samuel 2:21:16), a giant.

According to Radak, Ralbag, Metzudat David and Rabbi Steinsaltz, חצי המנחות (Chatzi Hamenuchot) (Chronicles 1:2:52).

According to Rashi, עזובה אשה (Azuva Isha) (Chronicles 1:2:18), a daughter of Kalev son of Chetzron (cf. Malbim on the verse).

As noted by @Yø-c Ro, עבד אדום (Oved Edom) (e.g. Shmuel 2:6:10).

Likewise, עבד מלך (Eved Melech) (e.g., Jeremiah 38:7-8), a servant of Tzidkiyahu.

Likewise, יושב חסד (Yushav Chessed) (Chronicles 1:3:20).

Likewise, טוב אדניה (Tov Adonyah) (Chronicles 2:17:8).

As noted by @moses, רממתי עזר (Romamti Ezer) (Chronicles 1:25:4), a Levite.

As noted by @Chani, מי זהב (Mei Zahav) (Genesis 36:39, Chronicles 1:1:50).

בעל חנן (Ba'al Chanan), a name shared by an Edomite king (Genesis 36:38-39, Chronicles 1:1:49-50) and a servant of David (Chronicles 1:27:28).

As noted by @Sholom, the Assyrian king תגלת פלאסר (Tiglat Pilesser) (and in one case Tilgat Pilnesser) (e.g., Kings 2:15:29).3

Likewise, the Babylonian king מרודך בלאדן/בראדך בלאדן (Merodach Baladan/Berodach Baladan) (e.g., Isaiah 39:1, Kings 2:20:12).3

Likewise, the Babylonian king אויל מרודך (Evil Merodach) (Kings 2:25:27).3

Likewise, עבד נגו (Aved Nego), the Babylonian name for Azariah, one of Daniel's friends (e.g., Daniel 1:7).

As noted by @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact, the Egyptian priest פוטי פרע (Poti Pherah) (e.g., Genesis 41:45).

According to Metzudat David, ישבי לחם (Yashuvi Lachem) (Chronicles 1:4:22).

As noted by @Sholom, perhaps כדר לעמר (Kedar Laomer) (see Chullin 65a and Minchat Shai on Genesis 14:1).

As noted by @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact, perhaps צפנת פענח (Tzophnat Pa'aneach) (Genesis 41:45).4

According to Rabbi Steinsaltz (and tentatively proposed by Ibn Ezra), פכרת הצביים (Pocheret Hatzevai'im) (Ezra 2:57).

According to Malbim, את יריעות (Et Yeriot) (Chronicles 1:2:18), a daughter of Kalev son of Chetzron.

Perhaps פחת מואב (Pachat Moav) (e.g., Ezra 8:4, Nehemiah 10:15).5

Perhaps בית רפא (Beit Rapha) (Chronicles 1:4:12).6


Thanks to everyone for their suggestions!

1 But see here for a different interpretation.
2 Cf. Hoshea 2:3.
3 The cuneiform name is also composed of multiple words.
4 Assuming Tzophnat Pa'aneach is a name rather than an official title of sorts.
5 Some propose that this was a title for various individuals. As a side-note, I recall once seeing a suggestion somewhere that this is where Rabbi Chiya's nickname for Rav, בר פחתי (Bar Pachti), comes from.
6 It's not clear in context whether this is a toponym or a personal name.

Thank you! Wikipedia claims that some commentators (e.g. Rashi) read "שאר ישוב" as words rather than a name, but I wasn't sure from reading Rashi if this is what he meant - is this a plausible reading in your view?

@c0d3rman yes, Rashi doesn't interpret this part of the verse in the plain sense. He viewed the words as a phrase referring to the people of Israel, or at least a part of them. Most of the other commentators, however, understand that Sha'ar Yeshuv was the name of Yeshuayahu's son (e.g. Malbim, Radak, Ibn Ezra).

עבד-אדום הגתי, עבד-מלך הכושי

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.9.5?lang=he?

Also אִישׁ בֹּשֶׁת

also "רוממתי עזר" in divrei hayamim.

No פלא יועץ אל גבור אבי עד שר שלום?

Also, the son לוט sired with the צעירה was named בן עמי and was the ancestor of the people known as בני עמון which typically gets shortened to just עמון.

@ba איש בשת is a parody of אשבעל (see Divrei Hayamim 1:8:33)

@JoelK and DoubleAA from pshat and commentators I'm familiar with, those are either titles given to Chizkiyahu or to Mashiach (or both), not actual names (though nowadays several have become real names, of course). But please feel free to refer to commentaries that may suggest otherwise.

@Sholom regarding Pesachim, I don't think Rav meant that the name was to be split apart in the text, but rather that the word was composed of two separate parts with an inherent difference.

@Harel13 I'm not sure why you call this a "title" not an alternate name. In any event, consider https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38673/759

@Harel13 No, that's not the simple read of the gemara. See too parallels https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.5.10 Debates about names being split or not is a favorite masoretic pastime, eg. https://yosefofer.com/papers/A%20Masoretic%20Note%20in%20the%20Aleppo%20Codex%20Concerning%20the%20Composite%20Words.pdf.

Isn't כדרלעמר written as one word? All sources I can find show it without the space.

פּ֥וֹטִי פֶ֛רַע
and צָֽפְנַ֣ת פַּעְנֵ֒חַ֒
Genesis 41:45

@c0d3rman Minchat Shai, whose commentary discusses mainly variances in the Masoretic tradition, noted that he did indeed find a few manuscripts (presumably chumashim and Torah scrolls) that have the name as two words.

@c0d3rman The Bavli says explicitly it's two words https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.65a.2 (related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103594/759)

יושב חסד (Divrei Hayamim 1:3:20) and טוב אדוניה (Divrei Hayamim 2:17:8)

מי זהב(Genesis 36:39) - although Rashi seems to understand that this was a nickname

Also עשה־אל from 2 Samuel 23:24
